# Delete item without navigating to new view--mvc 3

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a table in my site that shows a list of data. Each data item has a delete link. I don't  want to take my user to a delete page on click; I just want the item to be deleted before my eyes, on the same page, without navigating away. Do I still need to have a controller method for delete? How would I go about it, since I am obviously not returning a view with the delete click? I thought about using a redirecttoaction return on my get method for the delete, but I think that is incorrect.

What is the syntax for deleting without making a delete method return a delete view?

Comment: Whatever answer you go with, remember to only do this on a http post, otherwise a webcrawler will crawl your page, and delete each item in the database with these links.

Comment: @Oblivion2000 - lol, that is a good point. Moreover, (at)Skitterm, keep in mind that this can *only* be accomplished with some sort of implementation of ajax.

Answer (score 2):

Well if you have a table as such

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<a id="delete" href="@Url.Action("Delete",new {Id=123})">delete</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and a controller method

```
public JsonResult Delete(int Id)
{
//do delete stuff
return Json(true??false);
}
```

you would use ajax in the following way

```
$('#delete').click(function(){
$.post($(this).attr('href'),function(result){
if(result)
{
$(this).closest('tr').remove();
}
});
return false;
});
```

Comment: This looks good. I'm pretty new to MVC--where does the Json go? Is it a script that I create that i tell the view to use?

Comment: the script can go in your view if u like or can belong in one of your script files for that page its really your choice. the json is returned via the JsonResult object. within t script the parameter for the post function is the json value returned. It can be an object or just a value (as in shyju's answer ). mvc gives you all types of flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you could use Ajax fot this purpose. Than you could write something like the code below on onclick event of a button. Also you will need to provide some js code to hide deleted items.

```
$.post("delete/{Id}")
```

You might need to serialize form data, you can do this as well, with jQuery.

```
$.post("delete/{Id}", $("#form-name").serialize());
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a controller method that deletes the item.  Use JQuery (or your javascript library of preference) to respond to the click event on your button, and make an AJAX call.

controller code:

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    bool success = this.businessLogic.Delete(id); // whatever your business logic is for deleting

    object result = success ? "OK" : "ERROR"; // have this be your object that you will return
    return this.Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $("div.deleteButton").on("click", function() {
        var id = $(this).parent().attr("data-id"); // or wherever you've stored the id of the item you're trying to delete
        var url = "/Controller/Delete?id=" + id;
        $.getJSON(url, function (result) {
            if (result != "OK") {
                alert("delete failed!");
            }
            else {
                $("tr[data-id=" + id).remove(); // or however you need to remove the row from the UI
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

User jQuery ajax to do an asynchronous operation from the same list page.

Assuming you have some HTML markup like this.

```
<div class="divItem">
   <p>Item Desc 108</p>
   <a href="../Product/delete/108" class="ajaxAction">Delete</a>
</div>
<div class="divItem">
   <p>Item Desc 10p</p>
   <a href="../Product/delete/109" class="ajaxAction">Delete </a>
</div>
```

Now have some jQuery code. (make sure you include jQuery library in this view/Layout page for this code to work)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){

     $("a.ajaxAction").click(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();  //prevent default click behaviour
        var item=$(this);
        $.post(item.attr("href"),function(data){
           if(data.Status=="Deleted")
           {
             //successsfully delete from db. Lets remove the Item from UI
              item.closest(".divItem").fadeOut().remove();
           }
           else
           {
               alert("Could not delete");
           }

        });

     });

  });

</script>
```

Now make sure you have an action method in corresponding controller(*Product in this example*) to handle this jQuery `POST` and return `JSON` after the operation, back to the client.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
  try
  {
     //delete the Item from the DB using the id
     // and return Deleted as the status value in JSON
     return Json(new { Status : "Deleted"});
  }
  catch(Exception eX)
  {
     //log exception
     return Json(new { Status : "Error"});
   }

}
```

The Delete action method returns a valid `JSON` in the follwing form(Value of Status will be either Deleted/ Error)

```
{
    "Status": "Deleted"
}
```

In the callback of jQuery post you are checking the JSON data and ,If the status value is Deleted, you are removing the item from the UI DOM.